# jQuery(document) Click on element with preventDefault

Tags: jquery

I am using library, that add controll elements to DOM dynamically.
I am using this piece of code for dynamic elements:

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".mapbox-gl-draw_line",function(){
 console.log("CLICK");
});
```

However, that element has e.preventDefault on itself from JS library. Is there any way to catch a click event on dynamically created element, that has all those e.stop..,e.prevent,.. events on it? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem correct but you know, that you must add an event handler AFTER you added the element to the dome.

Comment: The problem is, that element is added and removed dynamically.

Comment: Then you have to add the handler dynamically too